# Vaadin animator example

Tags: java, vaadin

I want see some example of fade Animator in Vaadin, everytime I try animate some layout or component after button click nothing works, there is no documentation how to do it

Answer (score 2):

The best way of doing animations is to use CSS. You can have the button click add a classname to the element you want to animate and then define the class something like this (in your case you would add the class with Vaadin's addStyleName() method, not JS)

```js
document.querySelector('#hide-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.your-element').classList.add('hide');
});
```

```css
.your-element {
  transition: opacity 400ms;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.your-element.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-element"></div>
<button id="hide-button">Hide</button>
```

Comment: but I use Java, not js, there is no problem

Comment: Like I said, in your case you would add the classname in Java. Something like `new Button("Hide", ()-> yourElement.addStyleName("hide"));`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the animator addon?

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/animator

After installing it and compiling the widgetset you can use this:

```
Animator.animate(component, new Css().opacity(0));
Animator.animate(component, new Css().translateX("100px")).delay(1000).duration(2000);
```

Comment: I have this component and tried hundred times, nothing works, can you give me example for button click

Comment: If you wish us to help, then please show your code. There is a faq in stackoverflow what we need to anser "My code is not working" questions. (Answering such questions without seeing the code... I don't know how you think we will see what's the problem)

Comment: We are no longer accepting answers from this account., lol what? how can I add code if another restriction

Answer (score 0):

Try out CompAni (= Component Animator) for Vaadin.

[Vaadin Component Animator Addon](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/compani)

It works out of the box and offers a lot of amazing animations for components and layouts. Description and examples can be found here:
[Improve your Vaadin application with fancy animations](https://mekaso.rocks/improve-your-vaadin-application-with-fancy-animations)